# Identify Columns Index Matching Given Vector of String

Tags: r, matrix, vector, vectorization, string-matching

I've got a vector of string

```
x<-c('a','b')
```

and I have an matrix with multiple columnsl; which contains names in that vector of string. I would like to get the column numbers/index which matches their names.

```
which(colnames(sample_matrix) == x)
```

This above works when x is not a vector but a single element. Any solutions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try

```
 which(colnames(sample_matrix) %in% x)
```

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for is `%in%` as in:

```
which(colnames(sample_matrix) %in% x)
```

Or, alternatively, `match`

```
match(x, colnames(sample_matrix))
```

Answer (score 3):

Also:

```
grep("^a$|^b$", colnames(sample_matrix) )
```

Using grep is often more general that testing for presence in a string of values. You can get all the items that match a pattern, say all names that begin with "a".