# Get column index from data frame that matches numeric vector?

Tags: r, dataframe, vector

Very similar questions have been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427234/get-column-index-from-label-in-a-data-frame), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56142483/returning-the-index-of-vector-for-a-match), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14699911/identify-columns-index-matching-given-vector-of-string). However, they all seem to rely on knowing the column names of the data.

I am trying to get the column index of a data frame that matches a numeric vector. For example, if I have some data and a vector like so:

```
dat <- data.frame(
  x = c(1,2,3,4,5),
  y = c(10,9,8,7,6),
  z = c(2,4,6,8,10)
)

testVec <- c(2,4,6,8,10)
```

I would just like to return the column index of `dat` that matches `testVec` . We can see that `dat$z` matches `testVec`... so in this situation I would just like to return `3`.

Any suggestions as to how I could do this?

Comment: if `testVec <- c(10, 2, 4, 6, 8)` the result will be `3`?

Comment: No, in this case, there would be no match. The order of my `testVec` will always match the order of some column in `dat`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a base R approach, which compares every column in `dat` with `testVec` to see if they are `identical`. Use `which` to output the column index if they're identical.

```
which(sapply(1:ncol(dat), function(x) identical(dat[,x], testVec)))
[1] 3
```

**UPDATE**
@nicola has provided a better syntax to my original code (you can see it in the comment under this answer):

```
which(sapply(dat, identical, y = testVec))
z 
3
```

Comment: Just `which(sapply(dat, identical, y = testVec))` is cleaner I guess.

Comment: You're right! I'm too used to using custom function, I forget we can do this. Great tips!

Answer (score 1):

You perhaps can try this

```
> which(colSums(dat == testVec) == nrow(dat))
z
3
```

Answer (score 1):

An option with `select` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
   select(where(~ all(testVec == .x))) %>% 
   names %>% 
   match(names(dat))
[1] 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Subtract the `testVec`.

```
which(colSums(dat - testVec) == 0)
# z 
# 3
```

Without name:

```
unname(which(colSums(dat - testVec) == 0))
# [1] 3
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), y = c(10, 9, 8, 7, 6), z = c(2, 
4, 6, 8, 10)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
testVec <- c(2, 4, 6, 8, 10)
```